# Type inferring doesn't work properly when saving List of objects in Hive box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a list of hive objects i need to save, within whiche there is another list of hive objects, for example:

```
@freezed
class CorrectionDestination extends HiveObject with _$CorrectionDestination {
  CorrectionDestination._();

  @HiveType(typeId: 4)
  factory CorrectionDestination({
    @HiveField(0) required int stepId,
    @HiveField(1) required String stepTitle,
    @HiveField(2) required String stepType,
    @HiveField(3) required bool isCurrentStep,
    @HiveField(4) required int projectStepId,
    @HiveField(5)
    @JsonKey(defaultValue: [])
    required List<DestinationResults> results,
  }) = _CorrectionDestination;

  factory CorrectionDestination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CorrectionDestinationFromJson(json);
}
```

and my destination results looks like

```
@freezed
class DestinationResults extends HiveObject with _$DestinationResults {
  DestinationResults._();

  @HiveType(typeId: 5)
  factory DestinationResults({
    @HiveField(0) required int stepResultId,
    @HiveField(1) required String stepResultTitle,
  }) = _DestinationResults;

  factory DestinationResults.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DestinationResultsFromJson(json);
}
```

The problem occurs when im trying to cast the List to List:

`final box = await Hive.openBox<List<CorrectionDestination>>('correctionDestinations');`

Althought i can clearly see the object from the print statement (if we'll remove generic type from the openBox function):

```
final availableDestinations = box.get(inspectionId);
print(availableDestinations);
```

I've double checked my adapters and have following flutter doctors output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on macOS 14.2 23C64 darwin-arm64, locale en-UA)
    • Flutter version 3.16.3 on channel stable at /Users/lesha/fvm/versions/3.16.0
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0366e0a3f (5 weeks ago), 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 54a7145303
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected, because the list you're getting from Hive is considered as "collection from an external data source".

See [Invalid casts](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#invalid-casts), on this part:

> In cases where you are working with a collection that you don’t create, such as from JSON or an external data source, you can use the cast() method provided by `Iterable` implementations, such as `List`.
>
> Here’s an example of the preferred solution: tightening the object’s type.
>
> ```dart
> Map<String, dynamic> json = fetchFromExternalSource();
> var names = json['names'] as List;
> assumeStrings(names.cast<String>());
> ```