# Unable to obtain Map<String, dynamic> data from Flutter Hive storage due to type casting issues from _Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-hive, freezed

In my Flutter project I have set up static local repository functions where I can perform CRUD operations easily. I would serialize my Flutter objects into Map<String, dynamic> instances (JSON-like) using `toJson()` function generated by Freezed package.

But as I try to retrieve the data, an error stacktrace shows:

```
E/flutter ( 6461): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6461): #0      BoxImpl.get (package:hive/src/box/box_impl.dart:44:26)
E/flutter ( 6461): #1      LocalRepository.getAppWatchlist (package:project_intervene/services/repository/local/local_repository.dart:30:14)
...
```

It's really weird because I did explicitly state the type of my Hive Boxes to be in type `<Map<String, dynamic>>`, as proven by the following snippet.

```
await Hive.initFlutter();

await Hive.openBox<Map<String, dynamic>>(BOX_APP_WATCHLIST);
```

The GET function looks like this:

```
static Future<AppWatchlist?> getAppWatchlist() async {
    Map<String, dynamic>? data =
        Hive.box<Map<String, dynamic>>(BOX_APP_WATCHLIST)
            .get(KEY_APP_WATCHLIST);    // <-- Where #1 stacktrace is pointing
    return data == null ? null : AppWatchlist.fromJson(data);
}
```

The `AppWatchlist` model class is partially generated by Freezed.

#### What I have tried...

I tried to use `Map<String, dynamic>.from()`, but it does not work as the error occurs internally with Hive's get method. I couldn't even get the data.

When I try to store the object as strings, it cannot be decoded back into JSON properly as the keys and values do not have the quotation marks around them (JSON cannot determine their types that way). I also don't really want to store them as strings because of performances, unless if it really is the last resort.

#### Weird phenomenon

A strange phenomenon is that retrieving data did actually work, but seemingly only after I used the Update operation (of the same Hive box and key) once! The updater method looks like this:

```
  static void setAppWatchlist(AppWatchlist appWatchlist) {
    Hive.box<Map<String, dynamic>>(BOX_APP_WATCHLIST)
        .put(KEY_APP_WATCHLIST, appWatchlist.toJson());
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you save the data as `AppWatchlist`, instead of `Map`? You can use the [type adapter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter)

Comment: See also: [collection from an external data source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803912/13625293)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Nice article! I think I will be using HiveObject and Adapter instead of Map<String, dynamic> now. But still I am more inclined to Map since relying on HiveObject potentially poses scalability issues when I want to store data online, like using the Firebase (or maybe I am overthinking).

Comment: What's good about this article is that it tells users to augment HiveObject to Freezed objects. Surprisingly simple.

Comment: Don't worry, your Flutter app still uses the model class that you created (in this case, `AppWatchlist`). Hive adapter is just a way to translate the model into object that Hive can save on its local database. Firebase may also has its own way of saving objects that we're not aware of, but it doesn't affect how the Flutter app interprets the data. As long as you have the serialization methods (toJson and fromJson), you can easily convert the model to anything!