# save list<map> in hive

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

i want to save <List<Map<String, dynamic>> in hive but don't know how to do it

i tried to
this

```
   class AppPreferences {
    static late Box boxOfMaps;

  static Future<void> initHive() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();


 boxOfMaps = await Hive.openBox<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>("maps");
}



// Save map data
static void setMapData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> newMaps) {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> existingMaps = getMapData();
  existingMaps.addAll(newMaps);
  boxOfMaps.put("maps", existingMaps);
}

// Retrieve map data and return as a list
 static List<Map<String, dynamic>> getMapData() {
 return boxOfMaps.get("maps") ?? [];
}
```

}

but when i retrieve

```
   List<Map<String, dynamic>> retrievedMaps =  AppPreferences.getMapData();
```

i get this error

```
    type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>?' in type cast
```

is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type inferring doesn't work properly when saving List of objects in the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803871/type-inferring-doesnt-work-properly-when-saving-list-of-objects-in-the-box)

Comment: not really 
is there way that save these maps 
  Map<String, dynamic> map1 = {
                                      'url': 'url1',
                                      'name': 'name1',
                                      'format': 'format1'
                                    };

Comment: It literally is the answer to your problem. You have to cast the list after retrieving it from the box, so change the return line to this: `return boxOfMaps.get("maps").cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()`.