# How to read nested lists of objects firebase database flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested-lists

i am trying to retrieve a list of nested objects in firebase realtime database in flutter
here is the data:
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

let me explain:
i have a list of **Lessons**
every lesson has
id
pdfLink
title
and a list of **QuestionGroup**
every questionGroup has
frenchWord
frenchTranslation
...
and a List of **Questions**
every question has
id
title
and a list of **answers**
every answer has
id
title
here is the classes

Lesson Class:

```
class Lesson {

  String? id;
  String? pdfLink;
  List<QuestionGroup>? questionGroups;
  List<Question>? questions;
  String? title;
  String? videoLink;
  String? yearId;
  
  

  Lesson({
    this.id,
    this.pdfLink,
    this.questionGroups,
    this.questions,
    this.title,
    this.videoLink,
    this.yearId,
    
  });
factory Lesson.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Lesson(
      id: map['id'] ,
      yearId: map['yearId'] ,
      title: map['title'] ,
      pdfLink: map['pdfLink'],
      videoLink: map['videoLink'],
      questionGroups: map['questionGroups'],
      questions: map['questions']
    );
  }
}
```

QuestionGroup Class:

```
class QuestionGroup {

  String? id;
  String? frenchWord;
  String? arabicWord;
  String? frenchTranslation;
  String? arabicTranslation;
  
  
  List<Question>? questions;

  QuestionGroup({
    this.id,
    this.frenchWord,
    this.arabicWord,
    this.frenchTranslation,
    this.arabicTranslation,
    this.questions,
    
  });
```

---

Question Class:

```
class Question {
  String? id;
  String? title;  
  String? rightAnswer;
  List<Answer>? answers;
  Question({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.answers,
    this.rightAnswer,
    
  });
}
```

Answer Class:

```
class Answer {

  String? id;
  String? title;

  Answer({
    this.id,
    this.title,

  });
}
```

---

Here the code i use to read the lessons:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
       DatabaseReference yearsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('lessons');
          yearsRef.onValue.listen((event) {
            for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
              log('message');
              final lesson = child as Lesson;
              lessons!.add(lesson);
              log(lesson.toString());
              }
            }, onError: (error) {
              // Error.
            });
```

---

the problem : `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<QuestionGroup>?'`

it cannot retrieve the QuestionGroups list so it is not casting and not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type inferring doesn't work properly when saving List of objects in Hive box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803871/type-inferring-doesnt-work-properly-when-saving-list-of-objects-in-hive-box)

Comment: It's about reading a List from Hive, but the idea of "reading a list from an external resource" applies here too

Comment: i tried to build this function 
---
static List<QuestionGroup> fromlists (List<Object?> list){
  var questionGroups = list as List<QuestionGroup> ;
  return questionGroups;
}
---
and use it in lesson mapping :

      questionGroups: QuestionGroup.fromlists(map['questionGroups']),

------
but i get this error which is the same:

Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<QuestionGroup>' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `map['questionGroups']` to `map['questionGroups'] ==null? null : List<QuestionGroup>.from(map['questionGroups'].map(x=> QuestionGroup.fromMap(x)))`

Same goes for Question and Answer.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toJson' was called on null.

Comment: Please see the updated answer as your method is named as fromMap instead of fromJson. Also you have to have fromMap method in Question and Answer classes too.

Comment: i updated the code but had this error :     
Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'